# PHP Contact form error sending email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contact-form

I currently have a contact form on my index.html & contact.html pages. When testing the PHP contact form they do not send me an email or give any notification that the message has been sent, just appearing to do nothing.

HTML

```
<div class="form">
    <form action="php/contact.php" method="post">
       <h5 class="grey-bg text-center iq-font-black iq-tw-6 iq-pall-20">Service Inquiry</h5>
           <div class="iq-pall-30">
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-sm-12 iq-mtb-10">
                           <div class="section-field">
                                 <input name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" type="text">
                            </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-12 iq-mtb-10">
                           <div class="section-field">
                                <input name="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" type="text">
                           </div>
                      </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 iq-mtb-10">
                         <div class="section-field">
                               <select name="service" id="service">
                                    <option value="Choose Service" >Choose Service</option>
                                        <option value="test1" >test1</option>
                                        <option value="test" >Test</option>
                                    <span class="error">A service is required</span>
                                </select>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                     <div class="col-sm-12 iq-mtb-10">
                          <div class="section-field">
                                <input name="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phonenumber" type="text">
                           </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-sm-12 iq-mtb-10">
                          <div class="section-field ">
                               <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Comment" rows="5" id="comment" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
                          </div>
                       </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-12 iq-mtb-10">
                            <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send" class="button pull-right iq-mt-20">Send Message</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php $ToEmail = 'test@test.com'; 
$EmailSubject = 'User Contact Information'; 
$mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Service: ".$_POST["service"]."\r\n"; 
$mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."";
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Service: ".$_POST["service"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Phone: ".$_POST["phone"].""; 
$MESSAGE_BODY .= "Comment: ".nl2br($_POST["message"]).""; 
mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure");?>
```

The email's I do receive are like this:

```
User Contact Information
Name: Email: Phone: Comment:
```

Do the fields match the PHP form, and the send message button, how can that have a response for if the email has been sent or not?

Comment: You should limit the scope of your question to a single, discrete, answerable question. Your inquiry regarding implementation of verification and CAPTCHA would be better suited for a separate question.

Comment: First, you should always sanitize your inputs. Second, you will get an error or exception when you fail an email. If you want verification, you can do that in Javascript or PHP, and there are plenty of examples of both online. Captcha is easy to implement, again, lots of examples online

Comment: Thank you, I removed the Captcha question. I tried to make the question has straight forward as possible.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` to your POST data and see if it's there.

Comment: var_dump($_POST); var_dump($mailheader); var_dump($MESSAGE_BODY);

Comment: use phpmailer at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @LahiruTM This seems like hunting rabbits with an atom bomb - barring any additional complexity to this script, I would discourage OP from attempting to implement something as complex as PHPMailer when it seems that the built in `mail()` function will do just fine for their use case.

Answer (score 0):

A couple errors:

1. Your `<div class="iq-pall-30">` and `<div class="row">` elements are unclosed, which make your markup invalid and might affect the output you're getting to your PHP script.
2. You reference form elements that doesn't actually exist in your form:

   1. `$_POST["phone"]` is probably supposed to be a reference to your HTML form element `<input type="text" name="phonenumber">`. You'll have to change your variable reference to `$_POST["phonenumber"]` to correctly retrieve the data.
   2. `$_POST["message"]` is probably supposed to be a reference to your `textarea` form element, but you haven't assigned a name to that element in your markup. You should add `name="message"` as an attribute of the `textarea` in order to correctly retrieve that data.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the two div's and also fixed the data type.
I tested out the send function and this is what i'm receiving now
Name: Email: Choose ServicePhone: Comment:

The typed in information does not appear for each section though, how can I fix that?